# Is there a way to get information about a failed deploy on Travis-ci

Tags: docker, dockerfile, travis-ci

i am working around docker and try to push a docker repository via GitHub & Travis-ci.
My push doesn't work and i don't find why. Can you help me to find my mistake ?
my repo : https://github.com/ty1l3r/Docker-Push-Travis-CI/tree/ebe9050a9c814dc2492364220b6e33daeabbad14

This is the travis job log

```
Worker information
0.15s0.00s0.01s0.00s0.01s
system_info
Build system information
0.02s0.01s0.63s0.24s0.05s0.00s0.04s0.00s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.01s0.00s0.00s0.02s0.00s0.01s0.34s0.00s0.00s0.00s0.01s0.00s0.10s0.01s0.81s0.00s0.09s6.03s0.00s2.71s0.00s2.45s
docker_mtu
resolvconf
services
3.02s$ sudo systemctl start docker
git.checkout
0.53s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=main https://github.com/ty1l3r/Docker-Push-Travis-CI.git ty1l3r/Docker-Push-Travis-CI
0.01s
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export USERNAME_DOCKER=[secure]
$ export PASSWORD_DOCKER=[secure]
rvm
0.65s$ rvm use default
ruby.versions
$ ruby --version
No Gemfile found, skipping bundle install
51.98s$ docker build -t [secure]/node2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  116.7kB
Step 1/10 : FROM node
latest: Pulling from library/node
0400ac8f7460: Pulling fs layer
fa8559aa5ebb: Pulling fs layer
da32bfbbc3ba: Pulling fs layer
e1dc6725529d: Pulling fs layer
572866ab72a6: Pulling fs layer
63ee7d0b743d: Pulling fs layer
8c322550c0ed: Pulling fs layer
3a9ca1673e31: Pulling fs layer
64feb390fd3e: Pulling fs layer
e1dc6725529d: Waiting
572866ab72a6: Waiting
63ee7d0b743d: Waiting
8c322550c0ed: Waiting
3a9ca1673e31: Waiting
64feb390fd3e: Waiting
da32bfbbc3ba: Verifying Checksum
da32bfbbc3ba: Download complete
fa8559aa5ebb: Verifying Checksum
fa8559aa5ebb: Download complete
0400ac8f7460: Verifying Checksum
0400ac8f7460: Download complete
e1dc6725529d: Verifying Checksum
e1dc6725529d: Download complete
63ee7d0b743d: Verifying Checksum
63ee7d0b743d: Download complete
3a9ca1673e31: Verifying Checksum
3a9ca1673e31: Download complete
64feb390fd3e: Verifying Checksum
64feb390fd3e: Download complete
8c322550c0ed: Verifying Checksum
8c322550c0ed: Download complete
572866ab72a6: Verifying Checksum
572866ab72a6: Download complete
0400ac8f7460: Pull complete
fa8559aa5ebb: Pull complete
da32bfbbc3ba: Pull complete
e1dc6725529d: Pull complete
572866ab72a6: Pull complete
63ee7d0b743d: Pull complete
8c322550c0ed: Pull complete
3a9ca1673e31: Pull complete
64feb390fd3e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bf60a164bc588967ce6e3342c9d6508bf9ad2e7e2a1c237315596eab3e13428b
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
 ---> ca36fba5ad66
Step 2/10 : RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in ead7eee85d04
Removing intermediate container ead7eee85d04
 ---> db5142aef70d
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in ae004d76578e
Removing intermediate container ae004d76578e
 ---> f99a31e3bd7f
Step 4/10 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in fc0ecc340d36
Removing intermediate container fc0ecc340d36
 ---> 6bb3caae8781
Step 5/10 : COPY package*.json /usr/src/app
 ---> 8b0315d294b6
Step 6/10 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 5b946ac6267a
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
added 495 packages, and audited 495 packages in 16s
14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
5 low severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice 
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 7.0.3 -> 7.0.6
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.6>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@7.0.6` to update!
npm notice 
Removing intermediate container 5b946ac6267a
 ---> 4d6532f814f7
Step 7/10 : RUN npm update
 ---> Running in e8ad49b808f6
up to date, audited 495 packages in 7s
14 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
5 low severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
Removing intermediate container e8ad49b808f6
 ---> ff33fe82d1a4
Step 8/10 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> 54d8de7e3027
Step 9/10 : EXPOSE 4000
 ---> Running in 60819e76c49d
Removing intermediate container 60819e76c49d
 ---> 7f28f29c75e4
Step 10/10 : CMD [ "npm", "start"]
 ---> Running in 0043ac3e416e
Removing intermediate container 0043ac3e416e
 ---> 0f99dd5d05d1
Successfully built 0f99dd5d05d1
Successfully tagged [secure]/node2:latest
The command "docker build -t [secure]/node2 ." exited with 0.
0.07s$ docker images [secure]/nodes2
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
The command "docker images [secure]/nodes2" exited with 0.
before_deploy
0.51s$ docker login -u="$USERNAME_DOCKER" -p="$PASSWORD_DOCKER"
dpl_0
1.37s$ rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
dpl.3
Deploying application
failed to deploy
```

This is my travis.yml

```
sudo: required
services:
  - docker

script:
  - docker build -t tyl13r/node2 .
  - docker images tyl13r/nodes2

before_deploy:
  - docker login -u="$USERNAME_DOCKER" -p="$PASSWORD_DOCKER"

deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: docker push tyl13r/DockerTravisCi
  on:
    branch: main
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM node
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm update
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```